# Eclipse EGit Repository Changed Scanner fails

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm running EGit in my Eclipse for local versioning. But now I got a problem that I don't find any cure against.

"An internal error occurred during: "Repository Change Scanner".
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Do you have any ideas what to do about this? Report a bug?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 0):

If you discover a bug check out bugs.eclipse.org and see if you can find it.

Test the latest nightly build.

Create a bug report with  as much useful information as possible, in particular you
should supply the full stack trace.